# how to have smooth movement of bouncing ball and bounciness should be straight when it collides with the edge of any 2DBoxCollider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am setting up an game where ball keeps on bouncing and it moves horizontally, so when it collides with the edges of any 2DBoxCollider its direction of bounciness changes and i also want to have an smooth movement of an ball as it starts moving in circles after sometime

This is for unity and i am using Rigidbody and 2DBoxCollider for ball and Edge collider 2D for platforms where ball will bounce.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    ballPosition = new Vector2(ball.position.x,ball.position.y);
}   

public void MoveLeft()
{
    vector2 dir = new Vector2(ball.position.x - 10000f,ballPosition.y);
    Vector2 newPosition = dir - ballPosition;
    transform.Translate(newPosition.normalized*5*Time.deltaTime);
}

public void MoveRight()
{
    Vector2 dir = new Vector2(ball.position.x + 10000f,ballPosition.y);
    Vector2 newPosition = dir - ballPosition;
    transform.Translate(newPosition.normalized*5*Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I just want to have smooth ball movement and bounce should be straight even `enter code here`when it collides with the edges of box collider.`enter code here`

Comment: Is it Unity2D project?

Answer (score 0):

See [`transform.Translate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html)

> If `relativeTo` is left out or set to `Space.Self` the movement is applied relative to the transform's local axes. (the x, y and z axes shown when selecting the object inside the Scene View.) If `relativeTo` is `Space.World` the movement is applied relative to the world coordinate system.

The general problem is that you translate in `Space.Self` so in the local coordinate system of the ball. Since it is a `RigidBody` might start rotating after a Collision → movement in circles.

Therefore you **would** have to use

```
transform.Translate(directionVector * distance, Space.World);
```

---

**however** note that when you are using `RigidBody` you should **not** translate the object through the `Transform` component using e.g. `Translate` but instead rather do it through the `RigidBody` component e.g. using  [`rigidBody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html)

> Moves the rigidbody to position.
>
> Use Rigidbody.MovePosition to move a Rigidbody, complying with the Rigidbody's interpolation setting.
>
> If Rigidbody interpolation is enabled on the Rigidbody, calling Rigidbody.MovePosition results in a smooth transition between the two positions in any intermediate frames rendered. This should be used if you want to continuously move a rigidbody in each FixedUpdate.

as this uses the physics engine and is faster and smoother depending on your physics and interpolation settings (also see [`RigidBody.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html).

Also the calculation of the direction you are using is a bit odd. You should simply use [`Vector3.right == new Vector3(1, 0, 0)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-right.html) which is basically exactly what your bit more complicated calculation results in.

```
private RigidBody2D rigidBody2D;

private void Awake()
{
    rigidBody2D = GetComponent<RigidBody2D>();
}

public void MoveLeft()
{
    rigidBody.MovePosition(transform.position + Vector3.right * -5 * Time.deltaTime);
}

public void MoveRight()
{
    rigidBody.MovePosition(transform.position + Vector3.right * 5 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

---

*Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear*